# Are there Anti-CSRF best practices available to ASP developers for reference?

Tags: windows-8, webforms, csrf

In case you wonder what it is:

> ([Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)) Cross-site request forgery, also known as a one-click attack or session riding and abbreviated as CSRF (sometimes pronounced sea-surf[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)) or XSRF, is a type of malicious exploit of a website whereby unauthorized commands are transmitted from a user that the website trusts.[2] Unlike cross-site scripting (XSS), which exploits the trust a user has for a particular site, CSRF exploits the trust that a site has in a user's browser.

Anyway, does anyone know of some good best practices ref docs?

Specifically, for Web Forms (if that really matters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start at: [Web Application Security Overview](http://www.nsa.gov/applications/search/index.cfm?q=Cross-site%20request%20forgery) in the references there are a few useful links, some of which appear to be closed now. One good reference is: [Bunch of references](http://www.nsa.gov/ia/mitigation_guidance/security_configuration_guides/applications.shtml)

I also recommend reviewing this search return:[NIST gov](http://www.nist.gov/search-results.cfm?q=Cross-site+request+forgery&btng=Search&num=10&sortType=L&scopeType=0&datefrom=&dateto=) is another good source especially.

Not certain which technology you are targeting, the nsa.gov has a large number of obscure references that are quite good.